# Reference a mask defined in one SVG document from within another

Tags: css, svg

I have the following snippet.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="test-pattern"
            width="100%"
            height="20"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            patternTransform="rotate(-45)"
        >
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="10" fill="white"></rect>
        </pattern>
        <mask id="test-mask">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#test-pattern)"></rect>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I would like to reference `#test-mask` in another SVG document within an HTML page using CSS:

```
.myStripedBar { mask: url(stripesTest.svg#test-mask); }
```

However, this does nothing. Only having `#test-mask` in the same SVG document as `.myStripedBar` seems to work. But that SVG document is dynamically generated by an external process, and there are multiple layers of APIs in the way that make it difficult to alter that SVG.

Am I doing this wrong, or is this a limitation of SVG? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What UA are you using? Firefox supports this for instance.

Comment: Chrome (latest). Is this known to be browser-dependent? I'll try it in Firefox tomorrow, but any solution has to work in Chrome, because that's what we tell our customers to use.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to download Chrome's source code and fix it then.